# Checkboxes on Dynamically Created Table (only 1 selected max per row)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a dynamically created table that has three checkboxes per table row. What I am trying to do is have only 1 checked checkbox per table row. So if the user has a checkbox checked and they click another checkbox in the same row, it will uncheck the previous box and check the currently clicked box. I have the following code:

```
$('.classCheckboxOne').on 'change', ->
  if $('.classCheckboxOne').prop('checked')
    $('.classCheckboxTwo').prop('checked', false)
    $('.classCheckboxThree').prop('checked', false)

$('.classCheckboxTwo').on 'change', ->
  if $('.classCheckboxTwo').prop('checked')
    $('.classCheckboxOne').prop('checked', false)
    $('.classCheckboxThree').prop('checked', false)

$('.classCheckboxThree').on 'change', ->
  if $('.classCheckboxThree').prop('checked')
    $('.classCheckboxTwo').prop('checked', false)
    $('.classCheckboxOne').prop('checked', false)
```

So this code works for the first row of my table, but then the rest of the tables will not behave properly. The only other way I know to handle problems like this is to use ids instead of class names, but this will not work for my case since the table is dynamically created so there will be multiple rows with table elements containing the same id. So my question is how to get the above functionality working on each of my table rows. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is what you have HTML radio-buttons for. Just make sure that the buttons in the same group have a unique name, perhaps an id together with the row number of the table.

```html
<input type="radio" name="x" value="one" checked> One
<input type="radio" name="x" value="two"> Two
<input type="radio" name="x" value="three"> three 
<hr />
<input type="radio" name="y" value="one" checked> One
<input type="radio" name="y" value="two"> Two
<input type="radio" name="y" value="three"> three 
<hr />
<input type="radio" name="z" value="one" checked> One
<input type="radio" name="z" value="two"> Two
<input type="radio" name="z" value="three"> three
```

BUT, if you want to do it using checkboxes, assign a classname for all checkboxes on each row. Then you can do something like this.

```js
// Checkbox onclick function
function selectOneInRow(event) {
  // Get all checkboxes with same classname 
  // as the one you just clicked
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.' + event.target.className);
  // deselect all with same class
  for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].checked = false
  }
  // but select the one you clicked
  event.target.checked = true;
}


// Just code to generate checkboxes
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var checkboxes = 3;
var rows = 5;

function createCheckbox(rowNumber) {
  var input = document.createElement('input')
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  input.className = 'checkbox-' + rowNumber;
  input.onclick = selectOneInRow;
  return input;
}

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes; j++) {
    el.appendChild(createCheckbox(i))
  }
  el.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.groupCheck').change(function(){
    $('.groupCheck').not( $(this) ).prop( 'checked', false );
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="groupCheck" name="post_id" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="groupCheck"  name="post_id" value="2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="groupCheck"  name="post_id" value="3"/></td>
</tr>

</table>
```